# Gitlab CI/CD AWS ECR authorization "Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://XXXXXXXX failed with status: 400 Bad Request"

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, amazon-ecr, 400-bad-request

I have a problem with Gitlab CI/CD, where I have a runner that tries to authorize into AWS ECR. The .gitlab-ci.yaml file looks like this

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build_and_push_docker:
  stage: build
  image: docker:19.03.12
  script:
    - docker build -t repo-image .
    - docker tag ata-repo-image:latest $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repo:latest
    - echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID | docker login -u AWS --password-stdin https://$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    - docker push $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repo:latest

download_signed_files_from_ecr:
  stage: deploy
  image: amazon/aws-cli:latest
  entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
  script:
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    - aws configure set default.region us-east-1
    - docker pull $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repo:latest
    - docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/downloads $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repo:latest cp /var/www/html/signed/*.deb /downloads/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - /downloads
  only:
    - master
```

I get this error when I tried to run it

```
$ docker tag ata-repo-image:latest $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repo:latest
$ aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
/bin/sh: eval: line 139: aws: not found
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Login and AWS Policy look okay. Authorization via the terminal was performed without any issue so I suppose there might be a problem with the runner configuration or something like that.

Comment: I dont see this line which you mentioned in your error "$ aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" in your .gitlab-ci.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding something like the following in your build stage:

```yaml
  - |
    apk update && apk --no-cache add binutils curl wget git jq && apk del libc6-compat && \
      GLIBC_VER=2.34-r0 && \
      curl -sL https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub -o /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub && \
      curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk && \
      curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk && \
      curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VER}.apk && \
      apk add --no-cache --force-overwrite glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VER}.apk && \
      /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 && \
      curl -sL https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip -o awscliv2.zip && \
      unzip awscliv2.zip > /dev/null && aws/install && ln -s $(which awscliv2) /usr/bin/aws
```

This should add needed libraries and install AWS CLI which is missing in the `docker` image you are using for your `build stage`.

It is not shown in the `.gitlab-ci.yaml` example you provided with your question, but in your posted error response, a second line:

```bash
$ aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
/bin/sh: eval: line 139: aws: not found
```

indicates that you are trying to authorize using AWS CLI, for which it printed an error `aws: not found`.